# Tomcat 6 can't find custom FileDirContext implmentation in WEB-INF/classes

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, classnotfoundexception

So my server.xml defines a `<Context>` tag with nested `<Resources className="my.MyFileDirContext">`, where `MyFileDirContext` extends `FileDirContext` and is in the appropriate place under `WEB-INF/classes`.

When I start Tomcat 6, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` trying to load `MyFileDirContext`.

Stepping through in the debugger, I can see that the classloader being used at the time doesn't have `WEB-INF/classes` (or `WEB-INF/lib`, for that matter) available to it.

The frustrating thing is, I had just this problem a few months ago when I last set up my build environment from scratch, and I forgot to write down the solution.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class needs to be visible to the Tomcat internals so it has to be placed in $CATALINA_BASE/lib.  You can place the JAR in there or the class as long as the class is under the appropriate directory structure.

Comment: I had to put it in $CATALINA_HOME (/usr/share/tomcat6/lib on my box) rather than $CATALINA_BASE, but that seems to have done it. Thanks!